# Pressing “less info” in SO profile is not working right on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, profile-page, design

When I click on less info link on my profile page (on Stack Overflow as well as on META), the less info box covers some links on page. Following picture explains it well:

[image]

Does it happens to anybody else ? is it a bug ?

OS: Windows 7, and browser: Google Chrome 19.0

Comment: I tried to [bat signal Jin about this before](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=939542#939542), but at the time couldn't reproduce it in Chrome stable (although it breaks in a less-bad way in Opera). Chrome 19 is stable now, right?

Comment: @TimStone hmmm..:-/ I am not sure that chrome 19 is stable.

Comment: @HarryJoy: The latest stable version is 19.0.1084.46.

Comment: @Dennis: I am using the same. Chrome 19.0.1084.46

Answer (score 2):

Having just updated my browser to Chrome 19.0.1084.46 (the current stable version), I can now reproduce exactly the behavior you describe.

When viewing my profile with expanded information, everything looks fine. But when I click "less info" from that view, the layout breaks:

[image]

If I then *refresh* the page, leaving it set to display "less info", the top info header no longer overlaps the tabs below it, but the right-hand column is still incorrectly sized. The header box no longer extends across the entire width of the page.

[image]

Same deal on Meta Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault. *Not* broken on the "grainy" theme used with the SE 2.0 beta sites.

Not a huge bug, but worth a few minutes' investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking away the `white-space: normal` override that currently applies to the last cells in each row makes the layout go from zero:

[image: as-is]

to hero:

[image]

I'm confident there's some other weird side-effect of doing that, though.