# "less info" layout issue - overlapping tabs

Tags: bug, profile-page, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small CSS issue on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133053/small-css-issue-on-profile-page)

"less info" block overlaps tabs:

[image]

PS: and on my personal opinion the layout is terrible: 7 fields and **a lot** of free space

PPS: yep, forgot to specify the browser: Chrome 19

Comment: which browser you are using ? please add that information in to question

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 19...